# Batch script error: "%%d was not expected at this time"

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

Hi I'm trying to create a loop that will go through folders and take their names and in each folder will get the names of the files.

it starts with:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%d in (Folder*) do
    for %%f in ("%%d"\*.bla) do (
"command list"
)
```

I get back a resonse at the beginning:

```
 %%d was unexpected at this time
```

I guess it got to do with the setlocal command, anyone has an idea?

Comment: missing `(` after first `do` and corresponding closing one

Answer (score 1):

It's missing two parenthesis. Here's the corrected code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%d in (Folder*) do (
    for %%f in ("%%d"\*.bla) do (
        rem "command list"
        echo %%f
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that this scripts below works.

```
@echo off
set parent=%1

echo Beginning from %parent%...
for /d %%G in ("%parent%"\*) do (
    echo Folder: "%%G"
    set child=%%G
    echo %child%
    for /r %child%\ %%H in (*.*) do (
        echo File: "%%H"
    )

)
pause.
```

Run with the root path as the parameter: `myscript.bat C:\Windows`.

`%%G` is prefered than other letters, because of [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html). But it is not required.

As I can see, `for /r path %%H in (*.*) do ()` is the correct form to use `for` for files. Your script is wrong about that. There must be some syntax error in your script, please post them all.

As per your requirement, this only digs one level deep: for all directories under the root, enters it and print all files' names. It does not differentiate directories under second and deeper levels. `goto` may be used to refine this.